# CakePHP: Include PHP file with script function

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I have a file called script.php, this is some php and some javascript mixed together. The mime type of this file is forced to javascript, so this is a normal javascript file, but extension php.

I'm tryng to insert this inside my layout throuh script function. If write:

```
echo $this->Html->script('rsravenna/script.php');
```

cakephp will try to insert script.php.js, how can avoid the append of .js?

Answer (score 1):

The appending of `.js` is [hardcoded](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/html-helper#line-523) in the [HtmlHelper->script()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperscript) function. Is there anything in your app, that keeps you from just including your script manually?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.php"></script>
```

Otherwise you could extend the HtmlHelper to pass the variable `ext` as part of the `options` array to `HtmlHelper->assetUrl`.

You could also do it the other way around, tell your server to parse .js-files in a specific folder as php to preserve the extension. If you're using apache, put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
```

Now you should be able to rename your myscript.php to myscript.js and still get it parsed. This would enable you to use the standard `script()`-function.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear to me what you're trying to do.  script is an HTML Helper used to include javascript not PHP.

You can do something like:

```
echo $this->Html->url('/rsravenna/script.php', true);
```

or

```
echo $this->Html->url(array(
    "controller" => "foo",
    "action" => "bar",
    "ext" => "php"
));
```

Why are you forcing the MIME type to .js ?

Comment: I assumed what he's trying to accomplish is dynamically generating Javascript with PHP.